# angular2 google map marker mouse enter and leave event

Tags: google-maps, angular

I am using angular2 google map.I want to open a Info window on mouseenter and need to close on mouseleave of marker.
http://embed.plnkr.co/YX7W20/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/es6-shim@0.35.0/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/systemjs@0.19.27/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    
  </body>
  
</html>


<!-- 
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it should work for you:

```
const baseAddEventListeners = (<any>SebmGoogleMapMarker.prototype)._addEventListeners;
(<any>SebmGoogleMapMarker.prototype)._addEventListeners = function() {
   this._markerManager.createEventObservable('mouseover', this)
    .subscribe(() => { this._infoWindow.open();  });
   this._markerManager.createEventObservable('mouseout', this)
    .subscribe(() => { this._infoWindow.close(); });

  baseAddEventListeners.call(this);
}
```

See also **[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/kx1T2f?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank for your reply.
In plunkr its working fine but in my system am getting below error 
Property '_addEventListeners' is private and only accessible within class 'SebmGoogleMapMarker'
Is this related to anguar2-goolge-map version related one? I am using  "angular2-google-maps": "0.12.0".

Comment: In SebmGoogleMapMarker.d.ts  _addEventListeners() is declared as private. Hence there is no way to write above code in google map 0.12.0.

Comment: your a lifesaver!!! I was having the same issue and this works. For those still having issues like typescript complaining about _addListners being private. You can change it to public in node_modules\angular2-google-maps\core\directives\google-map-marker.d.ts